# Making a list of lists with no refrences in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make a list of lists in a one-lined efficient manner, but I can't come up with any way to avoid having references.  This is what I have tried so far, obviously unsuccessfully:

```
>>> test=[[None]*3][:]*3
>>> test
[[None, None, None], [None, None, None], [None, None, None]]
>>> test[0][0]=0
>>> test
[[0, None, None], [0, None, None], [0, None, None]]
>>>
```

This is not what I want to happen.  What  I want is for 0 to be the first item of only the first list.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
test = [[None] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
```

(Note the `_` is just a convention for output that is irrelevant, in this case `0`, `1`, and `2`)

Comment: Thanks.  I was trying to get it down into one line so I was avoiding for loops.  I forgot that they can be compressed into one line like this.  By the way does using _ instead of a variable not store the number?

Comment: Exactly so. To further clarify your note: the `_` does not carry any special meaning to the interpreter -- it's entirely for readability's sake. It lets any future programmer know that we don't care what the result of `range(3)` is, we just want to go through `range(3)`

Comment: It does store it, but it makes it clear to future "archaeologists" that you don't care what it is.

Comment: you could do `for _ in lst: print _` and it will work as intended, but your colleagues will look at you funny because you've explicitly said "Hey iterate through `lst` but we won't use each element -- OH WAIT LET'S USE THAT ELEMENT ANYWAY"