# python - make a list with repetitive elements

Tags: python

I know if I want to create a list like this:

```
[0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2 0 1 2]
```

I can use this command:

```
range(3) * 4
```

Is there a similar way to create a list like this:

```
[0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2]
```

I mean a way without loops

Comment: As a curiousity, all the current answers contain a loop (even if it is part of a list comprehension). I'd be interested to see if there's a way to do it without using for/in

Comment: `sum(map(list, zip(*[ range(4) ] * 4)), [])` is without obvious loops ;-)

Comment: NumPy version: `(np.arange(12)/4).tolist()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) module is always an option:

```
>>> from itertools import chain, repeat
>>> list(chain(repeat(0, 4), repeat(1, 4), repeat(2, 4)))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

More general way is:

```
def done(group_count, repeat_count):
    return list(chain(*map(lambda i: repeat(i, repeat_count),
                           range(group_count))))
>>> done(3, 4)
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Comment: Well that answers my question! I had a suspicion it would involve itertools.

Comment: This second method proved to be the fastest way to do this.

Answer (score 7):

Integer division can help:

```
[x/4 for x in range(12)]
```

Same thing through `map`:

```
map(lambda x: x/4, range(12))
```

In python 3 integer division is done with `//`.

Beware that multiplication of a list will likely lead to a [result](http://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-create-a-multidimensional-list) [you probably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13058458/python-list-index) [don't expect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21416519/making-a-list-of-lists-with-no-refrences-in-python?lq=1).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can.

```
>>> [e for e in range(3) for _ in [0]*4]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

**Without any explicit "for"** :)

```
>>> list(chain(*zip(*([range(5)] * 5))))
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: Yeah, no obvious loop ;-)

Comment: This one is very fast as well

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

```
>>> sum([ [x]*4 for x in range(5)],[])
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>>
```

or

```
>>> reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, [ [x]*4 for x in range(5)])
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't use a loop in your current method, create one in an other?

```
range(0,1)*4 + range(1,2)*4 + range(2,3)*4
```

Comment: That doesn't scale ;-)